# Empty Struct gets populated with no apparent pattern in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am currently trying to create a method to populate `student` with data, while having it inside an array of `student`, in order to be able to process its data with ease later on.

I have created two structs:

```
typedef struct{
    char email[100];
    char name[100];
    char age[100];
    char score[100];
}student;

typedef struct{
    student *array;
}student_Array;
```

Then, within `main()`, I would declare them to be populated right after, using the `Student Score Data.txt`:

```
|NAME|E-MAIL|AGE|SCORE
|James|James@gmail.com|20 Years Old|20/50
|Charlie|Charls@gmail.com|21 Years Old|23/50
|Parker|prak@gmail.com|22 Years Old|26/50
```

```
int main(){
    char fileName[100];
    printf("Please enter file name:\n");
    
  
    scanf("%[^\n]",fileName);    
    char  *contents = readFileRaw(fileName); //Student Score Data.txt

    student_Array students;

    students.array = malloc(sizeof(student) * 100);


    if(contents != NULL)
    Fill_Contents(contents, students); //Method to fill the structs using the text file.
    else
    printf("its empty\n");

    free(contents)

    ...
    ...

}
```

However, after at some point, I have noticed that specifically one of the parameters, `students.array[0].name` was populated with a part of the text file when I have not.

Note that all the other parameters of the same index, email, age and score was behaving normally, and so did all of the parameters on greater indexes.

Here is what the terminal printed after it has assigned its values:

```
STUDENT 0 INFORMATION:
student 0's age is 20 Years Old
student 0's name is Old|23/50
|Parker|prak@gmail.com|35 Years Old|26/50/50James
student 0's email is └James@gmail.com
student 0's score is 20/50

 STUDENT 1 INFORMATION:
student 1's age is 21 Years Old
student 1's name is Charlie
student 1's email is Charls@gmail.com
student 1's score is 23/50

 STUDENT 2 INFORMATION:
student 2's age is 35 Years Old
student 2's name is Parker
student 2's email is prak@gmail.com
student 2's score is 26/50
```

At first, I assumed it had to do with the `Fill_Contents()` method that I had created has some error, but it became clear that it was not the case.

By removing from `main()` the above mentioned method, it printed this:

```
STUDENT 0 INFORMATION:
student 0's age is
student 0's name is Old|23/50
|Parker|prak@gmail.com|35 Years Old|26/50/50
student 0's email is └
student 0's score is

 STUDENT 1 INFORMATION:
student 1's age is
student 1's name is
student 1's email is
student 1's score is

 STUDENT 2 INFORMATION:
student 2's age is
student 2's name is
student 2's email is
student 2's score is
```

It has now suddenly appeared as if regardless of being assigned or not using the `Fill_Contents()`, it would have been already populated with `Old|23/50|Parker|prak@gmail.com|35 Years Old|26/50/50` for unknown reason.

My only suspect now is at the `students.array = malloc(sizeof(student) * 100);`, where it could have been something related to the memory, but I have no idea how to move on from here.

I hope this has been clear, and I hope someone could help me with this.
I'm new to c, so apologies if I missed out on something.

Comment: Until you initialize the memory with a value, its contents is undefined. Therefore, reading from that memory before initializing it produces undefined behavior. If you want to zero the memory, either use `memset` or allocate with `calloc`. Or, simply leave it uninitialized but never read from it. One such way is to keep track of how many records you _have_ initialized, and never read past the end of that.

Comment: Oh wow, I wasn't aware of those methods. It works now! I have a habit of double checking my code if they would work on every step, so I wasn't aware this would happen. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's an excellent habit. Keep it up!

Comment: @paddy: The contents of uninitialized arrays are indeterminate, not undefined, and reading from such an array results in indeterminate values, not undefined behavior. (If it were undefined behavior, any behavior would conform to the C standard, including aborting the program or executing other parts of the program, for example. Those are not permissible. Reading from the array must produce some value of the element type, although it may produce different values on different reads of the same element.)